# Is SMART disabled in all portable USB hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, smart

I own a few portable USB hard disk drives.

Recently after replacing my laptop's failing drive I was using GSmartControl (Linux) to access the SMART data on my disks, looks like all the external drives that have USB connectivity don't have SMART support.

I own 2 ADATA HD710 drives and a Western Digital MyBook 3 TB. All use USB 3.0 connectivity.

I use one ADATA drive for daily inceremental backups, and the 3 TB drive for only-copy of old data and backup disk images of my family's laptops etc.

I'm pretty sure the MyBook has a standard big SATA drive inside. Is exposing the SMART features not possible with a USB interface? Or is this something else?

On the other hand my SanDisk 32 GB USB 3.0 pendrive reports to be SMART-enabled (while displaying no data at all).

What's the matter? How do I know if my backup medium is in good shape if it won't even report bad blocks? Should I stop using USB drives for backups?

Comment: This looks close enough that it might answer your question: http://superuser.com/a/456003/153356

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux we have `smartmontools`. [Its website](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/USB) gives the insight. The most important fragment:

> To access SMART functionality, `smartmontools` must be able to send ATA commands directly to the disk. For USB devices, at least the following conditions must be met:
>
> - The USB bridge provides an ATA pass-through command.
> - This command is supported by `smartmontools`.
> - The operating system provides a SCSI pass-through I/O-control which works through its USB-layer.
> - SCSI support is implemented in the operating system interface of `smartmontools`.

Notice there are conditions independent of `smartmontools`. I guess the situation is similar with whatever tool you use.

I had two USB adapters and only one of them let me use SMART functionality (tested with one and the same HDD).

Comment: "GSmartControl is a graphical user interface for smartctl (from smartmontools package)" ([from the GSmartControl website](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/)).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not disabled. I own four Western Digital 2 TB external drives, and all four report their data using CrystalDisk under Windows 10.

Your issue is probably the tool or the OS you use.