# Is there a way to fix usb hard drive not detected by Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

The history is like this :
I have a 2TB Seagate USB 3.0 Hard Disk Drive (HDD) full of movie files which recently was very slow to open the folders in it (also slow to load the file when opened).

Although Windows 10 say that the HDD is healthy and already optimized, because of the slow to open/load, I optimize the HDD using Defraggler, a free software from piriform. Up until 83% the progressing bar in Defraggler stop "forever" (after I've waited it for almost 2 hours).

I can't shutdown the computer directly because I need to close the Defraggler first.
But even after I click the STOP button on Defraggler, after I've waited a long time, it still didn't stop. So, via Windows Task Manager, I "end task" the Defraggler. Then the Defraggler close.

Since that time already late at night, I didn't check how is the HDD at that time (after Defraggler close via "end task" in Task Manager). I just directly shutdown the computer, but then the computer didn't want to shutdown. It just hanging there with a message "shutting down". After I unplug that HDD, then the computer can shutdown.

This morning I turn on the computer without problem. 
When I connect that USB HDD, the HDD led is blinking, the Windows Explorer of "This PC" show a progress bar on top of the window and this HDD show but only a drive icon with a drive letter. So I wait until the progress bar full, but still in "This PC" explorer, this USB HDD only show a drive icon with a drive letter  (this HDD led still keeps on blinking). There is no icon shown up in the taskbar for the connected external drive, so I can't do the "eject" safely this HDD.

So I just unplug this HDD, and I plug another older 2TB USB 3.0 HDD. Windows 10 directly recognize it, "kling" sound is heard, and in the taskbar for the connected external drive, this older USB HDD shown up. All is normal with the other two 2TB USB3.0 older HDDs.

I shutdown the computer. Unplug the older HDD, plug the "problematic" HDD. Turn on the computer. But Windows won't start, it just hang there with my motherboard logo "forever". Only after I unplug that "problematic" HDD, then the Windows can start. And this happen after yesterday I optimize the HDD with Degfraggler.

So this "problematic" HDD when already attached to the computer is causing Windows unable to start and Windows unable to shutdown. If it plug after the Windows start, Windows unable to detect it (showing a drive icon and drive letter only) and the taskbar for the connected external drive also not show up.

I've searched the internet and found some articles with similar problem, and mostly the article's solution is to do file recovery via third party software.

Since I think that to do a file recovery is my last resort, I would like to know if there is still a way to fix this, so I don't need to do the file recovery.

Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

EDIT:

Below is the "This PC" window :
[image]

Below is the task manager of that Drive P :
[image]

And below after cannibalism:
[image]

From youtube, I saw Seagate cannibalism - and it has SATA port + power port.
But it seems mine doesn't have it. Is there still a way that I can connect it internally ?

Oh ya I forget, when I open Disk Management, it unable to show all the hard drive attached to the computer unless I unplug that Drive P.

Comment: Probably Windows can no longer read the drive, perhaps because of errors. Since Explorer still shows the drive letter, you can try to check it and possibly [repair](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/check-hard-drive-fix-failures-windows-10/) it

Comment: I think your drive was already failing. Defragging it likely killed it completely, you really shouldn't have done that. Nest step, get the drive mounted internally to eliminate the enclosure as the source of the issue then run SMART tests. Report results into your question.

Comment: @spike, thank you for the comment. Yes, it still show a drive icon and drive letter, but there is no bar box for the size used/free and also no information something like _"200 GB free of 500 GB"_. Before optimizing it with Defraggler, I've check it with Windows optimization tool, and it say "Optimized". But still to open a folder (and load a file) takes a long time. That's why finally I use Defraggler.

Comment: @Tetsujin, that's what I thought in the first place (before use the Defraggler) that my drive is failing because to open a folder/file takes a long time. But Windows say that my drive is healthy and optimized. I never thought that I can mounted it internally, but based from your information, I will have a look the internet on how to cannibal the hard disk enclosure and connect it directly. Thank you for the suggestion, Tetsujin.

Comment: Windows doesn't know the 'health' of a USB-connected drive because USB does not transmit SMART data [which is why to do anything more you need to get it mounted internally]. Fragmentation does not equate to health.

Comment: @Tetsujin, please have a look my edited question. I put an image of the HD without enclosure. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.jax184.com/projects/verbatim/verbatim.html

Comment: @karma - You have experienced a HDD failure, the fact the drive performance was poor before you attempt to remove file fragmentation, in an indication the drive was failing.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can pull smart data from my external USB hard disk and it's monitored by speedfan ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - hmm, I've never been able to - seems to be hardware dependant https://superuser.com/questions/159522/what-determines-whether-s-m-a-r-t-data-can-be-retrieved-from-an-external-usb-dr

Comment: @gronostaj, LOL... that's way too difficult for me :). Thank you for your reference anyway.

Comment: @Ramhound, Yes I think so.

Comment: I'm looking around in my country if anyone sell an adapter from USB 3.0 hard drive to SATA... but it seems nobody sell here. The one they sell is from SATA hard drive to USB 3.0 plug :(.