# What to do when USB hard drive suddenly became raw?

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive

On June 2020 I made a similar post about my USB hard disk failure in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1557732/is-there-a-way-to-fix-usb-hard-drive-not-detected-by-windows-10).

So, last July 2020 I bought a new 2 TB Seagate Slim USB hard drive.
The hard drive is full with HD movie mkv files.
The hard drive is always connected to the computer,
so I never do "safely remove hardware and eject media".

Today, when I turn on the computer suddenly it show :
[image]

So I click "Cancel", then it show :
[image].

I click OK, then I go to the "This PC" of Windows 10, and it turn out the Drive H: doesn't have information like other drives
[image]

So I have a look on the Disk Management:
[image]

Then I left click that "Disk 2 Basic Online" to see the properties in the volumes tab:
[image].

I found in the internet about to do the chkdsk if facing like this situation
But since there are different suggestions which are :

1. one article suggest to try to do the chkdsk
2. another article suggest not to do the chkdsk as it can damage the sector where the files are.
3. one article said that it's not possible to do chkdsk if the disk is RAW - another article said it's still possible to do chkdsk if the disk is RAW.

So I choose not to do anything first. I neither do chkdsk in cmd nor click the "check" button which available in the "This PC" drive H: properties in the "Tool" tab. I even don't try to open that Drive H: by double clicking it.

What I did is "safely remove hardware and eject media" then detached the drive from the computer.

I don't think I will do a data recovery process since that means I need to buy the data recovery program and I have to buy a new 2TB hard disk drive.

My question:
*Is there anything that I can do which is safe (won't damage the drive any further) to try to fix this problem within Windows 10 ? Is it safe to try to do the chkdsk or click the CHECK button in the "Tool" tab ?*

Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You shouldn’t be doing anything if the data on the disk is valuable.  At this point the drive doesn’t have a file system, this is likely a sign, the drive has started to fail.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I didn't do anything except checking the properties of the drive (like in the photos), then detach it from the computer. It's quite surprising for me if the drive has started to fail since the drive is just 5 months old.

There are two USB hard drives which always connected to the computer. This new drive and another one is a 5 years old 1TB WD My Passport. Both of these two USB drives contain only data, no operating system and no "portable" program. The WD drive works normal.

Thank you once again for your comment.

Comment: You have had two usb external HDDs failed, that indicates potential environmental issues, USB external drives often use budget HDDs inside which have a lower lifespan than internal hdds

Comment: @Ramhound, no ... the one that fail (became RAW) is only the new 5 months old one. The 5 years old one (WD My Passport) works normal, no problem at all.

Comment: You said your HDD failed in June, you purchased a new drive in July, and that’s what this question was about.  That would be two drives not one that have failed.

Comment: Yes you are correct. What I mean is, when the first one failed on June, it's a 2.5 yo drive while the 5 yo drive not fail. Today, the one fail is the new 5 month old drive, the 5 yo drive not fail. If the environmental issue, I wonder why the 5 yo drive not affected.